# Unable to use `blocks` and `chainstate` from external drive

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, windows, datadir

I want to use data directory from a different location (external SSD) on a Windows machine. When I save the path for it in `bitcoin.conf` it still uses old data directory. How can I use `datadir` in `bitcoin.conf`?

`bitcoin.conf` file:

```
datadir=F:\bitcoin-mainnet
```

`debug.log` logs:

```
2021-03-05T01:34:22Z Config file arg: datadir="F:\\bitcoin-mainnet"
```

It still uses old data directory which doesn't have data for a synced full node (mainnet):

[image: data-dir-info]

Comment: This post could be improved by stating explicitly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This got resolved but not sure why specifying path in `bitcoin.conf` for `datadir` doesn't work.

**Workaround:**

Open "*%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Bitcoin Core*"

Right click on "Bitcoin Core (64-bit)" and go to properties.

The target for this shortcut should be *"C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -datadir=F:\bitcoin-mainnet*

**OR**

Open command prompt/powershell and run "bitcoin-qt.exe" with `datadir` path

C:\Program Files\Bitcoin>bitcoin-qt.exe -datadir="F:\bitcoin-mainnet"

[image: full-node-sync]